# Can I use the Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl in a page?

Tags: ribbon

My target is to hide the ribbon for visitors. For site owners it needs to be visible. I googled around and find something like this below. Is this also working on pages or only in masterpages?

```
<Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl ID="SPSecurityTrimmedControl2" runat="server" PermissionsString="AddListItems">
        <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("s4-ribbonrow").style.display = "block";
        </script>
    </Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
```

If this is not working in pages, is there some other solution to hide the ribbon only for visitors?

I am not looking for a development solution. Just something in spd or javascript or sometething?

Comment: It is working on pages, but ribbon is not added in the page layout but in the masterpage

Comment: so, how can I implement a solution to hide the ribbon only on 1 page?

Comment: You could have your own control that iterates all controls from code behind, and find ribbon and based on a condition (like permissions) hide or show it.

Comment: I am not looking for a development solution. Just something in spd or javascript or sometething?